# Not able to Create a Cloud Dataproc Custom Image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Hi i am new to GoogleDataProc and trying to create Custom Image for dataproc. I have followed all the steps as mentioned in documentation but while running it i got SuccessMatch found "BuildSucceeded: Dataproc Initialization Actions Succeeded."  and after that i am getting following error:

Command From my local machine with gcloud sdk installed :

python generate_custom_image.py --image-name xyz --dataproc-version 1.2.45 --customization-script customization_script.sh --daisy-path ~/daisy --zone abc-center-b --gcs-bucket gs://xyz_bucket

And got error as :

Error running workflow: step "create-image" run error: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.family': 'None'. Must be a match of regex  '(?:[a-z] (?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)', invalid

Please help me find the cause.

Comment: What is the exact command you run to create the custom image? Do you use `generate_custom_image.py` script?

Comment: Yes I am using python generate_custom_image.py and passing all required arguments as exactly mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Could you share how you invoke generate_custom_image.py (bleeping out the sensitive bits)?

Comment: Yes added command for your reference and invoked from my local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the cause of this is a [recent change](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-dataproc/commit/cecbc085bb379f9a139dfbc1dfd980dac169203c#diff-e448284acbb1f018b7d8394dc75cff13).

Just add `--family dataproc` to your invocation.

I created a [pull request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-dataproc/pull/68) to fix this.

Comment: Yes it helps to create an image thanks for that. But now its giving another issue while doing smoke testing error as : " This request exceeds CPU quota. Some things to try: request fewer workers (a minimum of 2 is required), use smaller master and/or worker machine types (such as n1-standard-2) ". I have tried suppling machine type of  n1-standard-1 then also got same error.  Is there any way to supply workers and masters in same command? documentation don't show that. But thanks for your help.

Comment: That error comes from cluster that is used in validation workflow. It needs 12 vCPU to run. You can try a zone/region where you have more quota?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but for smoke test its better to have parameters to launch single node or multiple node cluster with n1-machine. But thanks for your help.